# Swagger Annotation to add a json example to the response class

Tags: java, swagger-ui, spring-restcontroller

[image]

How can I insert a default value instead of the "{}" using swagger annotations?

Comment: It would be helpful to show the code / annotations you currently use. In general you specificy a Response class in the `@ApiOperation` / `@ApiResponse` response value. Example values are provided throug the `@ApiModel` and related annotations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to annotate your Rest method with ***@ApiResponses*** and ***@ApiResponse***.

For example

```
@ApiResponses(value = { 
                        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successful retrieval of demand",responseContainer="List"),
                        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Demand does not exist", response = Your Error response.class),
                        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal server error", response = Your Error response.class) 
                    }
            )
```

Annotate your Json Response class with ***@ApiModel*** and its field with ***@ApiModelProperty*** like

```
@ApiModel(description = "Your comment")
public class Demand implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Your comments", required = true, example = "example value")
    private String demandId;
}
```